# jQuery Bounce: Bounce, delay, loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Anyone familiar with [jQuery Bounce](https://github.com/ghepting/jquery-bounce)?

Does anyone know how to make something bounce, then put a delay, then make it bounce again?  This would then loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attribute data-loop to 1 on your element so it will only loop once.

```
 <img class="bounce" data-loop="1"  src="./demo/ball.svg" alt="Bouncing Ball" />
```

Then you can call the bounce function in a setInterval like below. Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
setInterval(bounce, 5000);

    function bounce()
    {
        $('.bounce').bounce();
    }
```